# Setting up domain with WAMP / XAMPP

Tags: security, xampp, web, wamp, hosting

I was wondering about *security* with setting up a domain for WAMP / XAMPP.

Lets say that I want to publish website hosted on my PC with WAMP or XAMPP.

So, I have to register a domain.. and set it in WAMP / XAMPP. But, what would happen, if I set some already used domain in WAMP? For example if I set **stackoverflow.com**, which is already registered. What would happen? I guess that people *will not see my website*, but this one (*stackoverflow*), but how does WAMP or XAMPP **recongnise that it is my website**?

I am begginer with this matter, so please, dont be angry if its something obious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are forgetting about DNS Servers and what they do.

When your browser see's any domain name you enter in the address bar, it goes to a DNS Server and asks, "Please give me the IP address for this domain name". *Domain names are only there for us humans as its easier to remember `stackoverflow.com` than it is to remember an ip address, and that gets even more difficult for us to remember if it is on the IPV6 network.*

So unless you can get all the DNS Servers in the universe changed to point the domain name `stackoverflow.com` to your routers external IP you wont effect anything by setting WAMP or XAMPP to use any existing domain name.

But lets say you do set WAMP/XAMPP to use an existing domain name. You would amend your HOSTS file to tell the Browser where to find that domain like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com

::1 localhost
::1 stackoverflow.com
```

This has the effect of seeding the local machines DNS Cache with these addresses. Now the browser will always check the DNS Cache before committing to the expence of asking a DNS Server to get the ip address, so your browser thinks that `stackoverflow.com` lives on your PC i.e. for IPV4 `127.0.0.1` or for IPV6 `::1`

All this will do is stop you getting to the real `stackoverflow.com` because the browser will attempt to connect to `127.0.0.1` every time you use `stackoverflow.com` as a domain name in the browser address bar instead of going to the real ip address for SO.

**Reply to your comment**

When you register a domain, you normally get access to an admin panel of some sort, where you set the ip address to use for this domain. This will set the DNS Server of who you purchased the domain from and this is then automatically propergated to all top level DNS Servers.

At that point you would set this to the *External IP/WAN IP address* of your router.

***But be aware***, if your ISP allocates IP addresses to you dynamically i.e. not a Static IP address you cannot do this, as your ISP Allocated IP Address is liable to change over time.

***As a final note***

WAMPServer and XAMPP are designed to be single seat developer tools and not LIVE Servers. That is not to say that the Apache in them is somehow less capable but that there is so much more to securing a web site than first meats the eye.

Also, you may not realise, but a Windows desktop OS is not a good target to run a live web server on. They are configured to be clients and as such have various limitations, mainly that a desptop OS can only manage around 20-30 external connections MAX. So if your site actually takes off, you are going to have a lot of complaints about the speed and accessibility of your site.

*This destop limitation cannot be reconfigured.*

Comment: thanks for answer. Let me just ask, if I register a domain and want to use it with XAMPP, do I have to work with theese DNS servers too? I want to host website publicly on my pc with .com domain. But I am not sure about the process of setting it up :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for update, I really appreciate it!
But am I right trhat WAMP / XAMPP are best (only) ways to host a website on my computer? You were talking about security, is there any better/safer way to host a website on my pc? 
You also mentioned disadvantages of using Windows to host a website, would you rather recommend Linux? But I can only use XAMPP then, right? 
Radek